# Blocking Express-API with sending 200 and continue execution?

Tags: node.js, express, blocking

Due to the given response time of an external API I use in my Express-App, I need to send back a 200 (Facebook expects a quick response) before the main work is done. This works as expected but...

***My question is:*** Do I block the API with this approach? What happens if other requests hit the API after the 200 but during the execution?

Schema / sequence:

> **[ Facebook ]**  --(request)-->  **[ my app ]**
>
> **[ Facebook ]**  <-----(200)----  **[ my app ]**
>
> ............................................ **[ my app ]** 
>   --(request)--> **[ ext. API ]**

My code:

```
app.post('/myapp', jsonEncoder, (req, res) => {

    externalHandling(req.body)
        .then(res => console.log(res))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));

    res.status(200).send('ok');
});
```

Comment: If other requests are received then the app will continue to process them without problem. The only issue will came if "externalHandling" function has inside some code that block the main thread as an infinity do-while or an very intensive cpu-task like image processing. Hope this help.

Comment: Thx you! "externalHandling" is performing two http-requests. On aims at Facebook again and one at a customers API. The problem with the latter one is that the response time is about 6 seconds which is way too much for Facebook, they expect a 200 within a shorter time period.